# plot in pyspark from a table

Tags: plot, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was doing a tables by pyspark and now I would like to plot this tables but I don't know how I can do it.

My table is like:

￼`t_sexo = spark.sql("SELECT SEXO, COUNT(SEXO) AS COUNT FROM acc_table GROUP BY SEXO ORDER BY COUNT DESC")
t_sexo.show()`

```
+-----------+-----+
|       SEXO|COUNT|
+-----------+-----+
|     HOMBRE|18871|
|      MUJER| 9797|
|NO ASIGNADO| 1454|
+-----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no plotting library in pyspark, you can either convert the DataFrame to pandas's DataFrame, use matplotlib there, or try something like [`plot.ly`](https://plot.ly/python/v3/apache-spark/), which claims to "Plot Data from Apache Spark in Python/v3"

Comment: But I don't know how I can convert the DataFrame to panda's DataFrame and do the same query and I get the same result

Comment: if `df` is a spark `DataFrame`, use `df.toPandas()` to convert to pandas DataFrame. 
Here's a guide for plotting with pandas.
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-pandas-and-matplotlib-for-data-exploration-56fad95f951c